# click() a button named 'submit' in Javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, dom-events

I have this HTML:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Invoeren" accesskey="s" class="buttons"/>
```

I'd like to click() it. I can not change anything on the HTML-side. When I do `getElementById("submit").click()`, I get this:

```
>>> document.getElementById("submit").click();
Cannot convert 'document.getElementById("submit")' to object
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can't edit the actual HTML (to add the id attribute), and you want this to be cross-browser, you could loop over all of the input elements and check the type and value attributes until it matches your submit button:

```
function get_submit_button() {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT');
    for(var i=0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        var inp = inputs[i];
        if(inp.type != 'submit') continue;
        if(inp.value == 'Invoeren' && inp.name == 'submit') {
            return inp;
            break; // exits the loop
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function click_submit() {
    var inp = get_submit_button();
    if(inp) inp.click();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

NOTE: NEVER call anything in a form "submit"! It will hide the form's submit event from script.

You have many ways of accessing the button

```
document.querySelector("[name=submit]").click(); // first named button

document.querySelector("#form [name=submit]").click(); // in form with id="form"
```

Old IEs would shadow the name so you could use getElementById on a name but it is not recommended.

Older methods:

```
document.getElementsByName("submit")[0].click();
```

where 0 is the first element on the page named submit.

```
document.forms[0].elements[0].click();
```

where `forms[0]` is the first form and `elements[0]` is the first element

or

```
document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].elements[0].click();
```

where `("form")[0]` is the first form on the page and `elements[0]` is the first element

Answer (score 1):

You are using `getElementById` but you don't have an `id` attribute on your input. Just because IE totally fubars the namespace and treats `name` attributes somewhat like `id` attributes does not mean that you should.

```
<input id="submit" ... />
...
document.getElementById('submit').click();
```

Answer (score 1):

The immediate issue i can see is that you have NOT assigned id `submit` to your input, so this won't work:

```
document.getElementById("submit").........
```

unless you specify the id as well:

```
<input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Invoeren" accesskey="s" class="buttons"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input has no id attribute so it can't be retrieved by id. Use this instead.

```
<input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Invoeren" accesskey="s" class="buttons"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, Is there a getElementByName function?

Answer (score 0):

There is no element with the ID "submit" -- you have an element *named* "submit".  As Dylan points out, jQuery would make everything easier, but you can fix it yourself.  If you cannot change the HTML, do something like this:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("submit");
for (var i=0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  var button = buttons[i];
  if (button.getAttribute("name") === "submit") {
     button.onclick = whatever ...
```

Answer (score -1):

You might want to look into jQuery.  It makes everything so, so much easier.