# How to simulate a mouse click in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following elements:

```
<input type="submit" name="add" value="add item" class="btn btn-add" onclick="addItem('add');return false;">
```

I want to write a Javascript to simulate a click of a mouse to add item to my shopping basket
I know you can use `document.getElementById('add').click()` but there's no Id here

I am very new to this and any help would be much appreciated

Comment: This question is already answered. Please chk http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571497/click-a-button-named-submit-in-javascript

Comment: That duplicate is the oldest on this site I think. It is not the best duplicate

Answer (score 2):

If you only have on element with name "add" you can also use:

```
document.getElementsByName('add')[0].click()
```

Comment: Thanks I've entered your script into the browser and this is what I am getting:

Uncaught ReferenceError: addItem is not defined

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use jQuery for this.
Using jQuery you can trigger a click like this:

```
$('#id').trigger('click');
```

In case you don't have an id but do have a class it might look like this:

```
$('.btn-add').trigger('click');
```

And of course with jQuery you can look at the parent dom element and 'find' the element you are looking for. eg:

```
$('#parentElement').find('button').trigger('click');
```

kudo's to [mplungjan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/295783/mplungjan) who came with:

```
$("input[name='add']").trigger('click');
```

another way you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript):

see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wrokf7L4/)

Comment: `$("input[name='add']")` would also be a way

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery library https://jquery.com

and in the code:

```
$( "input[name='add']" ).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using below javascript code.

```
   document.addEventListener("click", function(){
        document.getElementById("ID").innerHTML = "Click Event";
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the element by class

```
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-add');
```

Then call click on it

```
elem[0].click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some possibilities

```
document.getElementsByName("add")[0].click();
```

where 0 is the first element on the page named add.

```
var form = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0]; // change 0 to reflect the form
form.elements[form.elements.length-1].click(); // clicks the last button in the form
```

Alternative

```
document.forms[n].elements[m].click();
```

where n is the 0 based index of the form on the page and m is the 0 based index of the element in that form